# OracleDataAdapter Started Returning error ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, oracle11g, odp.net

Development Environment:
VB.NET
.net 4.5
ODP.NET
Oracle 11g

Hi there I have a weird problem, code in my development environment which has been working for a good number of years has suddenly stopped working.  The OracleDataAdapter returns the error ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.  However there is nothing wrong with the SQL that is passed to the adapter, the SQL executes successfully in SQLDeveloper.  It looks like the issue is with my VS development environment, as a previously compiled version of the application runs as normal.  I have re-compiled the entire VS solution and re-booted my development machine and then re-compiled without any joy.

The exact error returned is shown in the following log entry:

12|09:43:50|DOMAIN\USER|Trace|  Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container.InvokeMethod(Method TargetProcedure, Object[] Arguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, BindingFlags Flags)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.ObjectLateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
at QueryMain.uxBWFetch_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in d:\users\USER\Documents_VSSWorkArea\PSALERTS 2017\PSALERTS Client\Query\QueryMain.vb:line 677

Here is the code which generates the error:

```
        Dim myDataset As New DataSet
        Dim myUtils As New Utils

        _myConnection = New OracleConnection
        _myConnection.ConnectionString = _connectStr

        Try
            _myDataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(SQLStatement, _myConnection)
            _myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataset)
            _myConnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        Finally
            CType(_myConnection, IDisposable).Dispose()
        End Try

        Return myDataset

        GC.Collect()
```

The error is generated when we try to fill the dataset:

*_myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataset)*

If anyone has encountered this situation could you please let me know, as it is driving me to distraction!!!

Kind Regards
Paul J.

Answer (score 0):

Well now, don't I feel stupid.  Turns out although my intention was to develop against our test database, the SQL generated within the code contained a hardcoded connect string which was pointing at production, and of course the code contains references to new tables which are not in production, hence the error message... DOH...

Comment: In general, you should just follow what the message says. In this case it said the table is not there. For this reason, I was surprised you did not include the SQL statement itself. Common causes of this issue in Oracle include case sensitivity issues and of course, connecting to the wrong database ;).